# How to combine multiple txt files into one txt file using multi-threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, text

As I asked, I have multiple txt files:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
...
```

They're in the same folder, each file has a few lines. I want to merge them into one file using multithreading in Python.
Here is my code without thread:

```
filenames = glob.glob(DATA_DIR + '/*.txt')
with open('final.txt', 'w') as outputfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outputfile.write(line)
            outputfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: why thread? why not just read all append?

Comment: Just for experiment. (But it could be faster than just appending).

Comment: threading with files, it is most likely going to lead to a race condition, the hassle of locking (for this scenario) is not worth imo

Comment: but i really want to do it, can you give me help?

Comment: Draft a basic script that combines the file first without threading, then add on from there.

Comment: I see one idea - create pairs `(file1, file2)` and `(file3, file4)`, etc and send every pair to thead so it would join two files. After that would again create pairs to join them in threads. etc. But it may need to read and write the same files many times and it may not have to be faster. Using normal appending you have to read and write every file only once.

Comment: i believe OP's goal isn't actually to speed up a process, but rather a practice on threading.

Comment: @BurningAlcohol Check it sir!

Comment: yes, just practice on threading.

Comment: I also added the code using just appending!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example demonstrating a basic concept. You will have to play with what to do with `Lock()` to end up getting the result you need. But in short, this code is an example that the "threaded" version (`use_thread = True`) writes files in an inconsistent manner compared to the "non_threaded" version (`use_thread = False`) where the results are always consistent.

```
import threading

use_thread = True

def read_and_write_file(file_name):
    if use_thread:
        print(thread.name)

    with threading.Lock() as lock:
        with open('file_all.txt', 'a') as out, open(file_name) as in_:
            out.writelines(in_)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_names = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
    if use_thread:
        for file_name in file_names:
            thread = threading.Thread(target = read_and_write_file, args = (file_name,), name = file_name)
            thread.start()
    else:
        for file_name in file_names:
            read_and_write_file(file_name)
```